# Thymeleaf - passing a variable to controller

Tags: java, spring, http, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have a problem with Spring and Thymeleaf.

I have a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add")
public String addPage(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
    InvoiceData invoiceData = new InvoiceData();
    model.addAttribute("contractorid", id);
    model.addAttribute("invoicedata", invoiceData);
    return "add";
}
```

And I have an URI:

```
<li class="menu"><a th:href="@{/add/{id}(id=${contractor.id})}">Add invoice</a>
```

and of course, I have this `add.html` document containing a form to fill and save data to `ContractorData`.

But when I click the link, I get:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

And the URL in the browser looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/add/5c9e31b05b9b380a6b08dc94
```

So it is completely basing on the basic URI

How do I modify the URI or my code so I can pass the `contractor.id` to the /add controller and put it into `Model` so it will be available for me to use in add.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should help, i think.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}")
public String addPage(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
    InvoiceData invoiceData = new InvoiceData();
    model.addAttribute("contractorid", id);
    model.addAttribute("invoicedata", invoiceData);
    return "add";
}
```